# Validate forms with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I'm validating forms with ajax, but after validation, the alerts messages don't work. I don't know if the problem is in function the `.done` (Jquery) or the PHP page.

I hope you can help me.

HTML (crform21, crform22, crform23, crform44...)

```
   <form class="formus" id="crform21" name="crform21" method="post">
                <div class="crintro">Hola <strong>Fast</strong>, estás a punto de enviar una Cita Rápida a <strong>Maiers</strong> , rellena todos los campos y cruza los dedos para que 
                acepte. Hoy puede ser un Gran Día!</div><br>
                <h6><i class="icon-home"></i> Lugar de la Cita*</h6>
                <input type="text" value="" maxlength="250" name="crsite" id="crsite">
                <div id="addr">
                    <div style="width: 50%">
                <h6><i class="icon-home"></i> Calle*</h6>
                <input type="text" value="" maxlength="250" name="crstreet" id="crstreet">
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 50%">
                <h6> Número</h6>
                <input type="text" value="" maxlength="10" name="crnumber" id="crnumber">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h6><i class="icon-home"></i> Ciudad*</h6>
                <input type="text" value="" maxlength="250" name="crcity" id="crcity">
                <h6><i class="icon-home"></i> Código Postal</h6>
                <input type="text" value="" maxlength="250" name="crcpostal" id="crcpostal">
                <h6><i class="icon-calendar"></i> Fecha de la cita (DD-MM-AAAA HH:mm)*</h6>
                <input type="text" name="crfecha" id="crfecha" class="datepicker">
                <h6><i class="icon-lock"></i> Palabra secreta*</h6>
                <input type="text" value="" maxlength="250" name="crsecret" id="crsecret">
                <h6><i class="icon-comments"></i> Plan de la cita</h6>      
                <textarea rows="3" cols="20" name="crcomentario" id="crcomentario"></textarea><br>
                <input type="hidden" value="21" name="idreceptor">
                <input type="hidden" value="1" name="idcitador">
                <input type="hidden" value="Maiers" name="namereceptor">
                <input type="hidden" value="Fast" name="namecitador">
                <input type="hidden" value="http://www.fastdate.es/profile/easyloveadmin/" name="urlcitador">
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar cita" data-id="21" class="rating-button">
                </form>
```

PHP

```
//Si no se han rellenado todos los datos obligatorios o se intenta acceder al archivo sin estar logueado

 if(empty($lugar)){
     $errores['lugar'] ='Tienes que introducir un lugar para la cita';
 }
  if(empty($calle)){
     $errores['calle'] ='Tienes que introducir una calle para la cita';
 }
  if(empty($ciudad)){
     $errores['ciudad'] ='Tienes que introducir una ciudad';
 }
  if(empty($fecha)){
     $errores['fecha'] ='Tienes que introducir una fecha';
 }
  if(empty($pass)){
     $errores['pass'] ='Tienes que introducir una palabra secreta';
 }

if(empty($errores)){


    //Conexión Base de Datos

    include('conexion.php');

    //Guardamos la cita

    $grabarcita = mysql_query (
    "INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_author, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_content, post_title, post_status, comment_status, ping_status, post_password, post_name, post_parent, menu_order, post_type) " .
    "VALUES ('$citador','$hoy', '$hoy', '$contenido', '$title', '$publish', '$comment', '$pingst', '$pass', '$pname', '$parent', '$order', '$type')") or die (mysql_error());

    $grabarcitatabla = mysql_query (
    "INSERT INTO wp_citas (citador, idcitador, receptor,idreceptor, fecha, nomcita, passpriv, urlcita, estado, fechacita) " .
    "VALUES ('$namecitador','$citador', '$namereceptor', '$receptor', '$hoy', '$title', '$pass', '$urlcita', '$status', '$fecha')") or die (mysql_error());

    $datos['exito'] = true;
    $datos['mensaje'] = 'El registro se ha realizado correctamente.';

    //Enviamos Email de alerta de la cita a la persona citada

    include('sendmail.php');

    //Se cierra conexión con la Base de Datos

    mysql_close($link);

}else{
    $datos['exito'] = false;
    $datos['errores'] = $errores;
}

//Dar respuesta

 echo json_encode($datos);
```

I have this but function `.done` does not work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        var form = $('.formus');

        var url = '/controladores/grabarcita.php';

        var data = form.serialize();


    $(form).on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();  

        $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function(result){

        if(result.exito){
            alert("yes");
        }else{
            alert("no");
        }
        }).fail(function() {
            alert( "error" );
        });

   });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.. Here you must add questions in English.....

Comment: Hi karan, when I send data and validation happen, now always I receive the alert with "no", but It not run any error. Any idea?

Comment: Hello Fernando. Have you seen that there exists a Stack Exchange site called [Stack Overflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/) which is entirely dedicated to the Spanish language?

Comment: Bobulous I dont knew it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it appears as though `data` gets the wrong value, because you initialize it outside your form handler, so you you're sending all form data to your php file.  try instead serializing the form you're processing (using `$(this).serialize()` in the onSubmit handler) and using that as data:

```
$(form).on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();  

        $.ajax({        
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : url,
        // make sure you're sending this form's data!
        data    : $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        encode  : true      
        })  
        .done(function(datos){
        //Especificamos las respuestas para los datos recibidos
        if(datos.exito){
            alert(datos.mensaje);
        }else{
            if(datos.errores.lugar){
                alert(datos.errores.lugar);
            }
            if(datos.errores.calle){
                alert(datos.errores.calle);
            }
        }

        });

    });
```

now you should be sending the appropriate data over.  otherwise the logic seems sound, although i didn't test it.

good luck!

Comment: Thanks derelict, now I am sending the correct data to be validated, this is the output: {"exito":false,"errores":{"lugar":"Tienes que introducir un lugar para la cita","calle":"Tienes que introducir
 una calle para la cita","ciudad":"Tienes que introducir una ciudad","pass":"Tienes que introducir una
 palabra secreta","plancita":"Tienes que tener un plan para tu cita"}}
but the second part of the code doesnt work, the alerts with the messages dont work, would you know why ? Thanks

Comment: looks ok, try `console.log(datos)` in your `.done()` handler just to make sure that jquery parsed your response ok, and take a look at the network traffic in your browser's console to make sure the response body has the right type and content -- if it's still a mystery it might be time for a new question :)

Comment: Yeah, I have changed the title of question, I dont see the problem and looks ok, but I supose it could be in PHP file. Im trying other ways but nothing. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot type of data 'json' in function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        var form = $('.formus');

        var url = '/controladores/grabarcita.php';

        var data = form.serialize();


    $(form).on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();  

        $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function(result){

        if(result.exito == true){
            alert(result.mensaje);
        }else{
            alert("no");
        }
        },'json').fail(function() {
            alert( "error" );
        });

   });
});
```

Now It works!, Thanks.